# Unable to add into ArrayList then in Listbox C#

Tags: c#, database, arraylist, listbox

Want to loop the values in the arraylist into listbox. Currently, only the latest item in arraylist gets added into the listbox.

Code under button

```
                string strRating = txtRatingComment.Text;
                string strReturnedFilePath = db.retrievePictureRating(strRating);
                //clear album
                listBoxSearchResult.Items.Clear();

                //Add filepaths into arraylist
                pictureList.Add(strReturnedFilePath);

                //Loop arraylist into listbox
                for (int i = 0; i < pictureList.Count; i++)
                {
                    listBoxSearchResult.Items.Add(pictureList[i]);
                }
```

Code under Database class

```
 public string retrievePictureRating(string strRating)
    {
        string query = "SELECT pictureFilePath FROM picture where pictureRating = @pictureRating;";
        string pictureFilePath = "";

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictureRating", strRating);

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                pictureFilePath = dataReader["pictureFilePath"].ToString();
            }
            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        return pictureFilePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you create a variable:

```
string pictureFilePath = "";
```

Then inside the loop you always assign the value to the same variable:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    pictureFilePath = dataReader["pictureFilePath"].ToString();
}
```

So you always assign the value to the same variable, and so only the last line remains. You need to create a list to get all the values instead of just last one.

Comment: Adding to that, even the signature of your retrievePictureRating method suggests that it returns ONE string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
pictureFilePath = dataReader["pictureFilePath"].ToString();
```

This will override any of the other strings that function reads in from that loop.  You would need to have your function return an array of strings, and then add them. At the moment the array 'picture list' you create only contains one string.